# Pandas Merge. right_on conditional "OR"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to merge 2 dataframes. The Kicker: I would like to merge one column in the left dataframe against a possible 4 different columns in the right dataframe (i.e. if the match does not exist in column 1 of the right dataframe, then look in column 2, etc.)

(maybe based on a conditional OR statement).  Is this possible?

Example Code:

````
df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on = 'ID', right_on = ['ID' OR 'Second ID' OR 'Third ID' OR 'Fourth ID'])```
````

Comment: Can you craft some sample data and expected results?  You're going to need to merge four times and drop duplicates, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You stack the 4 columns on the right dataframe, merge this stacked frame to the left frame, then drop the duplicates.

Assuming you have these 2 dataframes and have pandas v0.25 or later (for `explode`):

```
df1 = 
  ID  Value
0  A      0
1  B      1
2  C      2
3  D      3
4  E      4
5  F      5

df2 = 
  ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4  AnotherValue
0   L   G   N   Y             1
1   H   U   B   F             4
2   O   Z   Q   V             1
3   H   A   T   P             6
4   V   K   A   G             3
5   E   C   N   U             1
```

Code:

```
# Combine values from 4 columns into a single row
s = df2.loc[:, 'ID1':'ID4'].apply(list, axis=1)

# Stack the 4 columns to form the right frame
right = df2.join(s.explode().rename('RightID'))

# reset_index: so that we have something to identify each unique row later
# merge: merge with the right frame
# drop_duplicate: each row in `df1` only matches to one row in `right`
df1.reset_index() \
    .merge(right, left_on='ID', right_on='RightID') \
    .drop_duplicates('index')
```

Result:

```
   index ID  Value ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4  AnotherValue RightID
0      0  A      0   H   A   T   P             6       A
2      1  B      1   H   U   B   F             4       B
3      2  C      2   E   C   N   U             1       C
4      4  E      4   E   C   N   U             1       E
5      5  F      5   H   U   B   F             4       F
```